# I have two datepicker in a component, I want to emit {startDate: startDateValue, endDate: endDateValue} if the date values are not empty

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is what I have tried but I get thesame date value for both inputs

```
export class DateComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() startDate: string;
  @Input() endDate: string;
  @Output() sendDate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() emitDate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  startMinDate: Date;
  startMaxDate: Date;
  endMinDate: Date;
  endMaxDate: Date;


  constructor(private moment: MomentService) {
    this.startMaxDate = this.moment.getMaxDate().toDate();
    this.startMinDate = this.moment.getMinDate().toDate();
    this.endMaxDate = this.moment.getMaxDate().toDate();
    this.endMinDate = this.moment.getMinDate().toDate();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onChange({ value }) {
    const ISOString = value.toISOString();
    this.sendDate.emit(ISOString);
  }

  changedDate({ value }) {
    const ISOString = value.toISOString();
    this.emitDate.emit(ISOString);
  }
}
```

***Parent Component.html, I need to bind these two output functions to the child component***

```
<app-date [endDate]="endDate" (sendDate)="endDate = $event" [startDate]="startDate"
          (emitDate)="startDate=$event"></app-date>
```

ChildComponent.html

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="endDate" [min]="endMinDate" [max]="endMaxDate"
            (dateChange)="changedDate($event)">
```

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [value]="startDate" [min]="startMinDate" [max]="startMaxDate"
            (dateChange)="onChange($event)">
```

Comment: Maybe not the best solution but you can have one or two boolean in the parent component change the value on sendDate and emitDate  pass those values as input to the child component and in the child  component check that value in your ngOnchanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue is that the two methods that fire when dates change are crossed. If you change them your code works as expected. So now you have:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="endDate" [min]="endMinDate" [max]="endMaxDate" 
(dateChange)="changedDate($event)">  <====== CHANGE THIS LINE

<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [value]="startDate" [min]="startMinDate" [max]="startMaxDate"
(dateChange)="onChange($event)">    <======== AND THIS LINE
```

Should be:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="endDate" [min]="endMinDate" [max]="endMaxDate" 
(dateChange)="onChange($event)">  <====== CORRECT!!!

<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" [value]="startDate" [min]="startMinDate" [max]="startMaxDate"
(dateChange)="changedDate($event)">    <======== CORRECT!!!
```

Check this Stackblitz I made base on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eroujf